# EF 4.0 - Load Navigation Property of Navigation Property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am attempting to perform the LoadProperty operation from my context to load a navigation property of a navigation property.

My setup is that I have an EntityA, which contains a list of EntityB's, and each EntityB contains a list of EntityC's. I am doing the following programatically:

```
public virtual List<T> LoadProperty(List<T> entities, string property)
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        foreach (T entity in entities)
        {
            context.AttachTo(typeof(T).Name, entity);
            context.LoadProperty(entity, property);
        }

    return entities;
}
```

I call it as such:

```
LoadProperty(entityA, "EntityB.EntityC");
```

I know that the NavigationProperty path is correct, however, this is not working. Is there a way to get this to load?

Edit:
Working example using Includes:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    var query = from entityA in context.EntityA.Include("EntityB").Include("EntityB.EntityC")
                where entityA.Id == id
                select entityA;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call both Inclued("EntityB") and Include("EntityB.EntityC"). The later one is enough.

Comment: EntityC is a collection on EntityB so there is NO EntityC on EntityB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your method call *context.AttachTo(typeof(T).Name, entity)* is not correct and you'll get an InvalidOperationException. [**ObjectContext.AttachTo Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attachto.aspx) shows:

```
public void AttachTo(string entitySetName, Object entity)
```

So we need to pass the EntitySet name and not the Entity name itself. But the good news is  we can get the EntitySet name from *MetadataWorkspace* by having the Entity name. The code below shows how.

Now if you have 3 levels of object composition and EntityB and EntityC are navigation properties of type EntityCollections, then I don’t think you could load them both with one call to LoadProperty, but you can do it by call LoadProperty twice, here is how it can be done:

```
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;

public virtual List<T> LoadProperty(List<T> entities, string property) {
    using (TrialsContext context = new TrialsContext()) {

        EntityContainer container = context.MetadataWorkspace
                                           .GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName,
                                                               DataSpace.CSpace);
        EntitySetBase entitySet = container.BaseEntitySets
                                           .Where(item => 
                                                  item.ElementType.Name.Equals(typeof(T).Name))
                                           .FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (T entity in entities) {
            context.AttachTo(entitySet.Name, entity);
            context.LoadProperty(entity, property);
        }

    return entities;
}
```

And you will call it:

```
// To load EntityA Nav property:
LoadProperty(entityB, "EntityA");

// To Load EntityC Nav property: 
//Let's assume the nav property name for EntityC on EntityB is EntityCList
LoadProperty(entityB, "EntityCList");
```

This way you will have the full object graph constructed.

Answer (score 1):

"I know that the NavigationProperty path is correct..." No it's not. Not with a list, it isn't. Try it with the regular `Include` and you'll see the same result. You can't do this with 1:* properties.

I can't imagine this is the most efficient solution to your problem, but you haven't actually shown why you think you need this.

Comment: I tested it with the Include and it worked. See edited ticket. Also there is a need for this when passing an instance of my EntityA around. The initial screen may not need a certain navigation property, but a subsequent screen may. Instead of re-loading the entity using the Includes, I would like to be able to just call LoadProperty to load the property I need. The LoadProperty method works for loading the property "EntityB", but not "EntityB.EntityC".

Comment: If `Include()` works, it will be more efficient than explicit loading. But projecting onto a view model will be more efficient than either one.

Comment: Reviewing the documentation for `LoadProperty`, I can't see any indication that it's intended to support a dotted path.